# How to set --rpath in configure script for openssl

Tags: linker, openssl, ld, configure, rpath

I have different `openssl` versions on my system and I don't want to install the most current `openssl` version into the system location - e.q. `/usr/bin/openssl`.

Now, when I compile `openssl` then I get this running `ldd`:

```
root => ldd /FaF/openssl/bin/openssl
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe60d92000)
    --> libssl.so.1.1 => not found
    --> libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007facf337b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007facf315e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007facf2dbd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007facf357f000)
```

I refer to `libssl.so.1.1` and `libcrypto.so.1.1` which are not found and this is OK that far.

Running `ldd` with preceded `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works:

```
root => LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/FaF/openssl/lib/ ldd /FaF/openssl/bin/openssl
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff221a1000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /FaF/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f45f842a000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /FaF/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f45f7f9a000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f45f7d96000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f45f7b79000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f45f77d8000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f45f869b000)
```

`/FaF/openssl/lib` is the directory where the correct libraries are.

**I have now these possible solutions:**

1. Adding `/FaF/openssl/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and running `ldconfig` - This is not really an option because it may break the system version of `openssl`.
2. As I did in the above example I can precede each time I need `openssl`with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/FaF/openssl/lib/` - not really a good option and it isn't always possible.
3. I can *link* the path with `--rpath=/FaF/openssl/lib` into `openssl`.

---

**My question:**
For the moment I didn't figure out how to set `--rpath=/FaF/openssl/lib` in the `configure` command which generates `openssl`. Can somebody provide me this information?

I tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LDFLAGS` but nothing works.

I prefer a solution which is *hard-coded* into `openssl` so there are not other settings required.

Comment: Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Here is the - very simple - way how to solve it according to 3) from my question.

I ran `./config -h` and got this output:

```
root => ./config -h
Usage: config [options]
 -d     Build with debugging when possible.
 -t     Test mode, do not run the Configure perl script.
 -v     Verbose mode, show the exact Configure call that is being made.
 -h     This help.

Any other text will be passed to the Configure perl script.
See INSTALL for instructions.

Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
Configuring for linux-x86_64
```

The text `Any other text will be passed to the Configure perl script.` says it all.

I just added the `--rpath` at the end to the `config` command which looks now like this:
`./config --prefix=/FaF/openssl threads shared -Wl,--rpath=/FaF/openssl/lib`

Comment: You can set the rpath to $ORIGIN and it will became relocatable, which I think it is the best.